# How to create and insert data into a new file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, autosys

I'm working on a autosys job which create a new file and insert filenames into that it. Currently im using below command which works based on the filename pattern. Unfortunatly this command is pulling wrong files with similar file name. So i wanted to create a command which will insert hardocded data into the file.

**Current Logic:**

```
find /home/temp/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*_File_Data.csv' -printf '%f\n' > /home/temp/File_Data.txt
```

**Current Output:**

`abcd_File_Data.csv` is not supposed to be selected.

```
$ cat File_Data.txt
a_File_Data.csv
b_File_Data.csv
c_File_Data.csv
d_File_Data.csv
abcd_File_Data.csv
```

**Expected Output:**

`abcd_File_Data.csv` was not selected.

```
$ cat File_Data.txt
a_File_Data.csv
b_File_Data.csv
c_File_Data.csv
d_File_Data.csv
```

Please let me know how to achive this scenario. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you are expecting "a_File_Data.txt" in output then you should first of all use " find /home/temp/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*_File_Data.txt' -printf '%f\n' > /home/temp/File_Data.txt "

Comment: Pacfist, Sorry that was a typo. It suppose to be a_File_Data.csv not .txt. update the post.

Comment: Please update your Q to show the incorrect output you have in `File_Data.txt`. I'm only guessing now, is your current data look like `/home/temp/a_File_Data.csv`? Why should I have to guess? ;-) OK? But you say ***pulling wrong files with similar file name***. Hmm. Still guessing ... ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: added the Current Output column as well. My goal is to create a new file and insert default data into it.

Comment: try `-name '[a-z]_File_Data.csv`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry, the file names i have listed are just for examples. The actual files are different. :)

Comment: So you either have to come up with a shell file glob that doesn't bring in unwanted files, or you have to name the unwanted files so they don't  match the best file glob you can come up with. OR just delete bad files after they have arrived? (`file glob` are things like `*_File_Data.csv` and `[a-z]_File_Data.csv`). `bash` (and ksh93, probably zsh) have negative fileGlobs as well, but they are tricky and documentation is for the cognezenti, which I am not ;-) . Without real filenames to test with, we're still guessing! Good luck.

Comment: Ah, and some versions of `find` support `-regex ...[a-z]_file` with more advanced matching options than the flle globbing available to the `-name` option.. Check `man find` and search here for examples. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199546/discussion-between-shellter-and-meet-rohan).

Comment: Tried this option. But didnt work as expected. `echo - e "a_File_Data.csv\nb_File_Data.csv\nc_File_Data.csv\nd_File_Data.csv " > /home/temp/File_Data.txt`

Comment: Also this `awk '{print $0 RS "a_File_Data.csv" RS "b_File_Data.csv" RS "c_File_Data.csv" RS "d_File_Data.csv";next}1' > /home/temp/File_Data.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your inputs on this question. 
Tried using the below command and it worked as expected:

`find /home/temp/{a_File_Data.csv,b_File_Data.csv,c_File_Data.csv,d_File_Data.csv} |xargs -n 1 basename > /home/temp/File_Data.txt`

Not sure if i have to use "-maxdepth 1" in my command but the above command worked even there are similar file names in the sub directories.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little stupid, but try this:

```
echo "a_File_Data.csv" > /home/temp/File_Data.txt
echo "b_File_Data.csv" >> /home/temp/File_Data.txt
echo "c_File_Data.csv" >> /home/temp/File_Data.txt
echo "d_File_Data.csv" >> /home/temp/File_Data.txt
```

Notice the first echo which uses a single ">" - it will empty the destination file first; the subsequent echoes will append.

Probably better: instead of repeating /home/temp/..., set a variable:

```
dest=/home/temp/File_Data.txt
echo "..." >> $dest
```

This will make the script more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command as it is

```
find /home/temp -maxdepth 1 -regex '^\/home\/temp\/[a-z]_File_Data\.csv$' -printf '%f\n' > /home/temp/File_Data.txt
```

Comment: Hi Prateek, The file names which i provided here are just examples. The names i deal in my scenario is different.

Comment: @MeetRohan My intention is to give you an understanding of using regex with the find command. Please update the regex for the file names of your case.